# Display Graph inside modal in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am new to MVC and I am using this link as tutorial in incorporating a graph from canvasjs inside a modal. https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/integration/asp-net-mvc-charts/

**Doing what is instructed in there (the static display only)**, it perfectly loads upon window load, as expected based on this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            theme: "theme2",
            animationEnabled: true,
            title: {
                text: "Simple Column Chart in ASP.NET MVC"
            },
            subtitles: [
                { text: "Try Resizing the Browser" }
            ],
            data: [
            {
                type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                dataPoints: [
                { x: 10, y: 71 },
                { x: 20, y: 55 },
                { x: 30, y: 50 },
                { x: 40, y: 65 },
                { x: 50, y: 95 },
                { x: 60, y: 68 },
                { x: 70, y: 28 },
                { x: 80, y: 34 },
                { x: 90, y: 14 }
                ]
            }
            ]
        });
        chart.render();
    };
</script>
```

What I want now, is follow the same simple instruction and display the graph, inside a modal.

I have a table where in one of its column has "view the graph" button" this process is set to dynamically display a graph based on the records from the database. but for now, I just want to display the graph in the tutorial link.

[image]

This button is calling a javascript function and calling an action in the controller where in inside the controller, it will pass the data gotten from the viewmodel to a partialview..

here's the javascript for the function

**patient.js**

```
   // Modal view user details
    function ViewVVSDetails(patientId, type, graph) {
        var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: { patientId: patientId, type: type, graph: graph },
            url: "/Patient/GetVisitVitalSignDetails",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#modalVVSDetailsContent').html(data);
                $('#modalVVSDetails').modal(options);
                $('#modalVVSDetails').modal('show');
            },
            error: function () {
                bootbox.alert({
                    size: "small",
                    title: "Error!",
                    message: "There is an error while loading data."
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

here's the view, where the div for modal is placed, and the main page where table and the button are located, will just show the code for the div modal

**patientInfo.cshtml**

```
<!-- Modal: Clinic Details -->
<div id="modalVVSDetails" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div id="modalVVSDetailsContent" class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here's the controller

**patientController.cs**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetVisitVitalSignDetails(int patientId, string type, string graph)
        {
            var visitSign = _patient.GetVisitVitalSignHeight(patientId);

            if (type == "h") 
            {
                if (graph == "hgn")
                {
                    return PartialView("_ViewVisitVitalSignDetails", visitSign);
                }
                else
                {
                    return PartialView("_ViewVisitVitalSignGraphDetails", visitSign);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (graph == "wgn")
                {
                    return PartialView("_ViewVisitVitalSignWeightDetails", visitSign);
                }
                else
                {
                    return PartialView("_ViewVisitVitalSignWeightGraphDetails", visitSign);
                }

            }
        }
```

and here's the partial view called (_ViewVisitVitalSignGraphDetails), where the code for displaying the graph is part of it. ***i Just removed the window.onload from the orginal code since it is not the idea now.***

```
_partielPatientModal.cshtml

@using UMP.ClinicalSystem.Models.Models;
@using UMP.ClinicalSystem.Models.Dto;

@model IEnumerable<VisitVitalSignVM>

@{
    Layout = null;


}

<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            theme: "theme2",
            animationEnabled: true,
            title: {
                text: "Simple Column Chart in ASP.NET MVC"
            },
            subtitles: [
                { text: "Try Resizing the Browser" }
            ],
            data: [
            {
                type: "column", //change type to bar, line, area, pie, etc
                dataPoints: [
                { x: 10, y: 71 },
                { x: 20, y: 55 },
                { x: 30, y: 50 },
                { x: 40, y: 65 },
                { x: 50, y: 95 },
                { x: 60, y: 68 },
                { x: 70, y: 28 },
                { x: 80, y: 34 },
                { x: 90, y: 14 }
                ]
            }
            ]
        });
        chart.render();
    });
</script>
```

I tried inputting text inside for testing, and it already showed the modal, **BUT NOT THE GRAPH**. So the sample javascript graph from the link does not work when put inside the modal, and AFTER I REMOVED the window.onload.

```
 <div id="chartContainer">sample text</div>
```

**Main question, How can I display the graph in the called modal**

Additional info

here's the result after going to the action result

[image]

Here's the screenshot of the showing modal already but not the graph

[image]

Comment: With the same code I am able to render the chart properly. Possibly the element could be hiding. Also put a `debugger;` statement inside Ajax success handler and check if the expected html from partial view delivered back. Also check with a break point if the control reaching to return `_ViewVisitVitalSignGraphDetails` inside your controller logic.

Comment: Hi, i put debugger in it, and it is actually going to success result, and the data actually results to the content of the partial view, which is the javascript codes calling the graph, but it results to just black background

Comment: i've updated the question, showing the image where in it actually goes to success block

Comment: So my question is, did you try to keep the response html directly inside a div on page? If it renders properly then it is a problem with your modal display but not the component or its rendering. Also update what component are using to show the modal?

Comment: Hi @SivaGopal i have updated my question and now included the div from view that is used in showing the modal. Would really appreciate your expert advice on this

Comment: After injecting response html into the div, Inspect/view source of that modal and check if the expected graph related html is present or not. If it is there, then check by increasing width & height of the div to some 500 px or so.

Comment: Also inside `$.ajax(...)` either try removing the `dataType` setting or try changing it to `dataType: "html"` and check.

Answer (score 0):

controller returning html view but your ajax request content type is json. Delete this line from  of ajax request.

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: I have removed that line but still the graph does not show in the modal.

Comment: putting debugger inside the javascript, it actually goes to success result, and the data inside  $('#modalVVSDetailsContent').html(data);
            $('#modalVVSDetails').modal(options);
            $('#modalVVSDetails').modal('show'); is the actual html codes in the partial view, but it is not popping right.

Comment: still the same sir... the modal is not popping up with the static graph,

Comment: you dont need call $('#modalVVSDetails').modal('show');..  Is there any javascript fault?

Comment: If i remove it, then the modal will not totally show,